# Binary Tree printing all paths

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, tree, binary-tree

Can the below design can be further optimized? I have used a hashmap and a Queue. SO space complexity will be O(n) and runtime will be O(n)

```
public class PrintAllRootToLeaves {

    public static void print(BinaryTreeNode root) {     

        Queue nodesQ = new Queue();
        HashMap hMap = new HashMap();
        BinaryTreeNode head = root;
        String tempVal ;        
        hMap.put(head,String.valueOf(head.getData()));
        while (head != null) {

            BinaryTreeNode left = head.getLeft();
            BinaryTreeNode right = head.getRight(); 

            if (left != null) {
                if ((tempVal = (String) hMap.get(head)) != null) {                  
                    hMap.put(left,tempVal + left.getData());
                }
                nodesQ.enqueue(left);
            }

            if (right != null) {
                if ((tempVal = (String) hMap.get(head)) != null) {  
                    hMap.put(right,tempVal + right.getData());

                }
                nodesQ.enqueue(right);
            }           
            if (right != null && left != null) {
                hMap.remove(head);
            }
            head = (BinaryTreeNode) nodesQ.dequeue();                       
        }       
        System.out.println("-----------Printing all routes ---------->" + hMap.values());               
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears you need to traverse every node, so I don't see how the complexity can be less than O(n). What you can do is use StringBuilder instead of appending to a String.

Comment: Why are you removing nodes from the hashmap in the loop, are you trying to only print the lowest tree nodes?

Comment: This can't be done in under `O(N*Log N)`, because you have `N*Log N` items to be printed.

Comment: @kditraglia, i am removing node from hashmap to get the paths from root to leaves and not the intermidiate path?

Comment: @Peter, what about space complexity, any suggestions?

Comment: The space complexity is going to be much the same no matter how you get your result. i.e. what you output is the only thing which matters at the end.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class BinaryTree {


    private class Node {
        final int key;
        final int value;
        Node left;
        Node Right;

        public Node (Node node, int pKey, int qValue) {
            key = pKey;
            value = qValue;
            if (node != null && node.key < pKey) {
                left = node;
            }
            else if (node != null) {
                Right = node;
            }
        }
    }


    public void preOrderTraversal(Node pNode,String path){

        if (path == null) {
            path = "";
        }
        if (pNode != null) {
            path = path+" "+String.valueOf(pNode.key);
//If you remove the modulo check it will print all the paths.
            if (pNode.key%5 == 0) {
                System.out.println(path);
            }
            preOrderTraversal(pNode.left,path);

            preOrderTraversal(pNode.Right,path);

        }

    }


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node node1 = new BinaryTree().new Node(null, 5, 2);
        Node node2 = new BinaryTree().new Node(null, 10, 25);
        Node node3 = new BinaryTree().new Node(node1, 7, 50);
        node3.Right = node2;
        Node root = new BinaryTree().new Node(node3, 15, 6);
        Node node4 = new BinaryTree().new Node(null, 30, 8);
        Node node5 = new BinaryTree().new Node(node4, 20, 7);
        root.Right = node5;
//This will print paths only divisable by 5
        new BinaryTree().preOrderTraversal(root,null);
    }

}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?